# how do i make this loop work

Tags: loop, featured-post

Apologies I am a PHp beginner and I have no idea why this loop is not working on my tag.php page any help would be welcome.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="posts"><!-- BLOG -->

    <!-- Shapes on sides -->
    <div class="shapes_left"> </div>
    <div class="shapes_right"> </div>

        <?php if (is_tag()) { ?>
            <div id="archive_title">
                <h1><?php single_tag_title(); ?></h1>
                <?php }?>
        </div>


    <div id="featured_home">        

        <?php $counter = 0;
            while ( have_posts() ) {
                $counter += 1;
                if ( $counter > 5 ) {
                    break; 
                    }
                    the_post();

         ?>
        <article class="sticky">
            <div class="desc">
                    <div class="desc_over"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></div>
                 <?php the_post_thumbnail(large); ?> 


            </div>
        </article>
        <?php }?>
        </div>





        <?php while( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            // it's a post! Display the post!
                    } ?>


            <div class="post_main">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <ul class="postinfo">
                        <li>Posted by <?php the_author_link(); ?></li>
                        <li><?php the_time( 'jS F Y'); ?></li>
                    </ul>   

                 <?php the_content( ''); ?>

                <div class="read_more_blog"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></div>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <nav id="pagination"> <!-- PAGINATION FOR BLOG -->
            <ul>
                <li class="older"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts'); ?></li>
                <li class="newer"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts'); ?></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        </div> 
        <!-- END OF BLOG PAGINATION -->
        <?php else : ?>
         <div id="post">
            <!-- 404 Messege -->
                <h3>404 ERROR!!</h3>

            <p>Sorry we can't seem able to find what you are looking for</p>
            <p><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">Click here to get back to the homepage</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Your while statement is incorrect and you have an else statement further down the page without having an if to start with, then there is an endif statement to close it but in fact it hasn't been started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clean it up some more but this will fix your code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="posts"><!-- BLOG -->

    <!-- Shapes on sides -->
<div class="shapes_left"> </div>
<div class="shapes_right"> </div>

    <?php if (is_tag()) { ?>
        <div id="archive_title">
            <h1><?php single_tag_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php }?>
    </div>


<div id="featured_home">        

    <?php $counter = 0;
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            $counter += 1;
            if ( $counter > 5 ) {
                break; 
                }
                the_post();

     ?>
    <article class="sticky">
        <div class="desc">
                <div class="desc_over"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></div>
             <?php the_post_thumbnail(large); ?> 


        </div>
    </article>
    <?php }?>
    </div>





    <?php
    // I've added the missing if statement and corrected some php grammar
    if ( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
        // it's a post! Display the post!
                 ?>


        <div class="post_main">
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <ul class="postinfo">
                    <li>Posted by <?php the_author_link(); ?></li>
                    <li><?php the_time( 'jS F Y'); ?></li>
                </ul>   

             <?php the_content( ''); ?>

            <div class="read_more_blog"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></div>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <nav id="pagination"> <!-- PAGINATION FOR BLOG -->
        <ul>
            <li class="older"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts'); ?></li>
            <li class="newer"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts'); ?></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    </div> 
    <!-- END OF BLOG PAGINATION  -->
    <!-- because the if statement has been started the else will now work  -->
    <?php else : ?>
     <div id="post">
        <!-- 404 Messege -->
            <h3>404 ERROR!!</h3>

        <p>Sorry we can't seem able to find what you are looking for</p>
        <p><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">Click here to get back to the homepage</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- now the if statement is ended  -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How did it fix the code though? What was wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

The correct iteration of the loop is:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

and ends here:

```
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For more details on the loop see https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Also I am not sure if your $counter variable means anything in PHP...

$counter += 1;

If you are trying to add 1 to the $counter variable you should do:

$counter++;

This will increase the $counter variable by 1